# Performance issue with Google Maps on iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps for an app and I observe the map have some very little lags when I move on the map with my fingers, it's very subtle.

When I compare to the Google Maps app or MapKit the difference is visible. 
I tried with the sample code from the SDK and the result is the same.
I don't understand why Google Maps app don't have the problem except if they don't use their own SDK.

I also noticed I had 60FPS with MapKit and only 30 with Google Maps.

I use an iPhone 5s and 6 on iOS 8.1.3 with Google Maps SDK 1.9.2 (latest version).

Comment: They might use different SDK for their Google Maps app.

Answer (score 1):

See the bug report at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5066.

Google Maps on iOS has always been artificially capped at 30 fps, because Apple's docs encouraged developers to max out at 30 fps for battery savings. I suspect that information is outdated. Almost every app on iOS refreshes at 60 fps. Google's own Maps app as of recently also refreshes at 60 fps, but the API doesn't. It's unknown if they will update the API or at least provide control.

Personally, I'm very sensitive to apps running at less than 60 fps, and it's annoying enough for me to choose a different app.